# No sound when playing mp3 in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

There is no error message when playing the sound.  I put a print statement for testing, and the url is getting the right path.  The play button clicks, and I hear a faint click sometimes, but that's it.  No other sound comes out.  I've tried different mp3 files.  I get an error message if I delete the mp3 file. I've checked the volume.

The play button is in a second view controller.  The main view controller has a table view.  When user taps on the cell, it takes him to this view controller.

```
//  DetailVC.swift

import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class DetailVC: UIViewController {

    var duaPlayer = ""  //is this correct???


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }



    @IBAction func playbutton(sender: AnyObject) {

        do {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("track1", withExtension: "mp3")

      var duaPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)

            duaPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            print (url)
            duaPlayer.volume = 0.5

            duaPlayer.play()
        }

        catch
        { fatalError("err")}

    }
```

Comment: Could be that duaPlayer gets deallocated before it starts playing, since it is a local variable. Try removing the var infront of duaPlayer in playbutton method.

Comment: duaPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)  // I took out the var, it does not compile, it says cannot assign value of type "AVAudioPlayer to type String

Comment: Of course, your duaPlayer is String. Change it to optional of type AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: please mark my question as helpful if it is, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that AVAudioPlayer do not support streaming. For live streaming use AVPlayer

```
//try this, it should work
var player = AVPlayer()
func configureView() {
    let url = "http://yoururl.com"
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
    player.rate = 1.0;
    player.play()
}
```

in the other hand , with AVAudioPlayer you can download the mp3 file first than play it -->

```
let url = "http://YourURL/music/music.mp3"
let fileURL = NSURL(string:url)
let soundData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(fileURL, options: nil, error: nil)
var error: NSError?
self.player = AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData, error: &error)
if player == nil {
  if let e = error {
    println(e.localizedDescription)
  }
}
player.prepareToPlay()
player.volume = 1.0
player.delegate = self
player.play()
```

**PS: Please keep in mind since iOS 9: App Transport Security (ATS) must be configured to accept non ssl connection.**
add this code to your info.plist->

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```